# making a runnable file from a binary file

Tags: ubuntu, binary-files

I have downloaded some programs from PortableLinuxApps.com  such as **Xnoise**, and **Chromium**, and have them saved on a USB with the intention of their being part of a Swiss-Army-USB holiday gift for my brother. However, they were binary files when I downloaded them and the site says that I need to make the programs executable before I can run them. How might I do this?

More importantly, can I do this in the next 24 hours? If not, is there a way around this restriction?

Comment: What happens when you try to run them now?

Comment: it displays an error message saying **could not display "/media/JAKE/Xnoise0.1.10"** JAKE is the name of the USB drive i am using and Xnoise0.1.10 is the binary file

Answer (score 0):

If your USB key is still FAT, you can't easily. What you *can* do is tell the loader to execute the binary file.

```
# /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /media/JAKE/Xnoise0.1.10
```

Comment: just ran the command. nothing happened

Comment: wait. i need this to work for my brother who has no technical knowledge whatsoever, and wouldn't know a terminal from a text editor. is there a way to make it runnable?

Comment: You would need to remount it with different permissions, which would require a terminal. Put the executable binary in a tarball instead.

Comment: how would i do that? (im kinda new at this if you cant tell... i prefer osX to linux)